# variable corresponding to a rowname in r

Tags: r

Now I have a `.df` looks like below:

`v1 v2 v3`

`1  2  3`

`4  5  6`

What should I do with rownames such that if `v2` of `rownames(df) %% 2 == 0` does not equal to `v2` of `rownames(df) %% 2  == 1`, then delete both rows?

Thank you all.

**Update:**

For this df below, you can see that for row 1 and 2, they have the same `ID`, so I want to keep these two rows as a pair (`CODE` shows 1 and 4).

Similarly I want to keep row 10 and 11 because they have the same `ID` and they are a pair.

What should I do to get a new df?

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your meaning? What do you mean by should delete both rows?

Comment: I want to remove both rows from the data frame if the conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: This question is confusing.  Please elaborate a bit more `v2 of rownames(df) %%2 ==0`  What is `v2` doing here

Comment: @akrun Ok, for this df, I need my 1st and 2nd row have the same value in v2, and 3rd and 4th row have the same value in v2, etc... When they are paired, I can run regression for other variables. So if they are not paired, I want to delete them in the df, because they are useless.

Comment: You have showed only 2 rows.  Please update your question and expected output

Comment: can you please paste data rather than show screenshot so as to make it easily reproducible

Comment: Yes, I would love to! But I am new to the site, and do not know how to do so... Can you help me edit it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a dataframe with  column for number of times the id comes

```
library(sqldf)
df2=sqldf("select count(id),id from df group by id"
```

2) merge them

```
df3=merge(df1,df2)
```

3) select only if count>1

```
df3[df3$count>1,]
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to keep paired IDs and delete the rest (I doubt it is as simple as this), then ..

1. Extract your ids: I have written them out, you should extract.
   `id = c(263733,263733,2913733,3243733,3723733,4493733,273733,393733,2953733,3583733,3583733)`
2. sort them
3. Find out which ones to keep.
   `id1 = cbind(id[1:length(id)-1],id[2:length(id)])`

`chosenID = id1[which(id1[,1]==id1[,2]),1]`

4. And then extract from your df those rows that have `chosenID`.